# How appstore handles credit amount on subscription upgrade/downgrade

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, app-store

example: from android in-app subscription:

For example, Samwise has a subscription to online content from the Country Gardener app. He currently has a monthly subscription to the Tier 1 version of the content (which has text-only content). This subscription costs him £2/month, and renews on the first of the month. On April 15, he chooses to upgrade to the Tier 2 subscription (which includes video updates), costing £3/month. His Tier 1 subscription is immediately ended. Since he paid for a full month (April 1-30), but only used half of it, half of a month's subscription (£1) is applied to his new subscription. However, since that new subscription costs £3/month, the £1 credit balance only pays for ten days. So Samwise's credit pays for his subscription from April 15-25. On April 26, he is charged £3 for his new subscription, and another £3 on the 26th of each month following

I want to know how IOS APP store handle it

Comment: I wish there was an answer.